# How to pull info from a string and output it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a game where the computer picks a random word and the player has to guess that word. The computer tells the player how many letters are in the word. Then the player gets five chances to ask if a letter is in the word. The computer can only respond with `"yes"` or `"no"`. Then, the player must guess the word.
I only have:

```
import random
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone", "truck" , "doom" , "mayonase" ,"flying" ,"magic" ,"mine" ,"bugle")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
print(len(word))
correct = word
guess = input("\nYour guess: ")
if guess != correct and guess != "" :
        print("No.")

if guess == correct:
    print("Yes!\n")
```

I have no idea how to do this problem.

Comment: How would you do it by hand? Write out some pseudo-code, even if it's really high-level.

Comment: use a counter and a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like below

```
import random

WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone", "truck" , "doom" , "mayonase" ,"flying" ,"magic" ,"mine" ,"bugle")

word = random.choice(WORDS)
correct_answer = word
max_guesses = 5

print("Word length:", len(word))
print("Attempts Available:", max_guesses)


for guesses in range(max_guesses):
    guess = input("\nEnter your guess, or a letter: ")
    if guess == correct_answer:
        print("Yay! '%s' is the correct answer.\n" % guess)
        break
    elif guess != "":
        if guess[0] in correct_answer:
            print("Yes, '%s' appears in the answer" % guess[0])
        else:
            print("No, '%s' does not appear in the answer" % guess[0])
else:
    print("\nYou ran out of maximumum tries!\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to let the user ask the computer if a letter is in the word, 5 times. If so, here is the code:

```
for i in range(5): #Let the player ask 5 times
    letter = input("What letter do you want to ask about? ")[0]
    #take only the 1st letter if they try to cheat

    if letter in correct:
        print("yes, letter is in word\n")
    else:
        print("no, letter is not in word")
```

The key is the `in` operator within the `for` loop.